# read() does not read data from pty despite they are

Tags: unix, pty

My program is supposed to emulate external device that is usually connected via COM port (/dev/ttyUSB0). The program opens a pty and waits for commands. Here is the code:

```
HostPty::HostPty(const string & HostPty_name)
{
    char name[100] = {0};
    int res = openpty(&_master, &_slave, name, NULL, NULL);
    printf("Name: %s\n", name);
}

string HostPty::nextString()
{
    static const int BUF_SIZE = 4096;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    size_t idx = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        // Read symbols one by one until new line is found
        size_t received_size = read(_master, buf + idx, 1);
        printf("Received a symbol: %02x\n", buf[idx]);

        // Stopping at new line
        if(buf[idx] == '\n')
            break;

        idx++;
    }

    return string(buf, idx);
}
```

To test this code I am using miniterm.py terminal emulator connecting to /dev/pty/6 (or whatever is created with openpty) and send text commands over there.

When I type commands manually everything works fine - I receive chars one by one as expected. But when I paste a piece of multiline text this code receives only first byte until I put a new line symbol (even though there are multiple newline symbols in the text I paste).

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas how to fix that?

I don't know which kind of Unix you have. I just tried to reproduce your problem under Linux; but pasting lines work fine on my computer so I cannot reproduce the problem.

If your Unix variant has a system call tracer (Linux: `strace`, SunOS/Solars: `truss`, FreeBSD: `strace`, MacOS: `dtruss` (?)), I'd trace the system calls:

```
strace -f -o file_myprog.out ./my_program

miniterm /dev/pty/6
```

(Note the `-f` which means that the system calls of sub-processes created by `fork()` are also debugged. This is necessary because Python will create such sub-processes.)

Now reproduce the situation when the program does not behave correctly and kill `my_program` using `pkill -KILL my_program`. (Send the `-KILL` signal to ensure that `my_program` is killed immediately.)

Do that again - this time debugging `miniterm` and killing `miniterm` in the "wrong situation":

```
./my_program

strace -f -o file_miniterm.out miniterm /dev/pty/6
```

At the end of the two output files (`file_myprog.out` and `file_miniterm.out`) you can see the last "actions" the two programs were doing before you killed them. There are various scenarios possible:

- `miniterm` was sending the data to `/dev/pty/6` but your program did not receive any data. In this case there is a problem with the virtual console itself.
- `miniterm` did not send the data to `/dev/pty/6` for some reason. In this case you have a problem with `miniterm`.
- `miniterm` did not even receive the data pasted using `read()`...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. I am running my program on RaspberryPi which runs under Raspbian.

Comment: I tried strace. Surprisingly it did not show any anomalies on either sides. Despite miniterm receives pasted text as one piece it sends it symbol by symbol (using write(1)). Same for my program which receives the data symbol by symbol with read(1). But for some reason when I am sending big piece of text my program receives only the first symbol, while others stuck somewhere in the pipe. When I send a piece of text, then kill miniterm - my program received whole bunch of data. Is there a buffering applied for pty?

Comment: A-ha. The problem is on miniterm side. I tried strace with -tt parameter and I now clearly see it sends only one byte of data when I paste a piece of text. The remaining part seems stuck in its buffer